# SQL Server 2016 Memory Optimized Table Implementation

Tags: sql-server

We are planning to implement memory optimized table for the replacement of #temp tables used inside the stored procedures.

Problem statements:

1. We have 80 stored procedures used for our healthcare measure calculations
2. 20 stored procedures taking 20 to 30 minutes for the entire calculations to be processed. All the 80 stored procedures are running one after another.
3. Inside the stored procedures we created on an average of 100 #temp tables to hold the intermediate results and the row count will be maximum of 1 million records.
4. We created index and performance has been optimized already. Due to the large volume of our base tables record read time also increases our time.
5. Base tables are partitioned quarter wise with 18 partitions for holding 4 years data, and the table has columnstore index and non clustered index in place.
6. Our database size is 2TB.

Question:

1. As per Microsoft recommendation MOTS can be introduce in database which does not exceed 250GB Size.  Ours in 2TB database. Is it possible to implement Memory optimized table?
2. We are planning to replace only the #temp table used inside the stored procedures to improve measure performance and reduce tempdb storage and utilization.
3. Our server is a physical and VM boxes holding 256 GB of RAM out 50 GB Allocated to OS and SQL server running with 200GB Memory.
4. Pagefile disk allocated with 50GB with system managed size configured.
5. Server storage holds 8TB Of 2 disk Holding database data files, 500GB For tempdb data files, 500GB For tempdb log, 500GB For database log.

Can we proceed with memory optimized table for the temp table replacement?

We already optimized our queries based on index, tempdb secondary files (Minimum of 8 files created for tempdb), 2 drives with 8TB of storage from dedicated SAN.

Comment: Memory-optimized tables are *not* meant to replace temp tables. You shouldn't be using temp tables in the first place. Fix your queries, your schema and indexes. If you want tables for staging create proper staging tables. Temporary tables are *not* stored in memory, they are stored in tempdb

Comment: And no, that's not why you want to use memory tables. If you think you need to pin data in memory to "improve performance" you have schema issues that need fixing. Memory tables are meant for high traffic scenarios where they offer minimal locking. Not for ETL jobs, temporary storage or "pinning" data in memory that shouldn't need pinning

Comment: What calculations are those that are too slow and why perform them at all? Reports should read data from separate reporting databases, *not* try to calculate reports on the fly. Even so, you may be able to run aggregate queries 100x faster by using *Columnstore indexes*, which offer compression *and* accelerated querying *and* in-memory processing

Comment: Dear Panagiotis, Thanks for the response. We already optimized our queries and we too implement paulwhite optimizations from sql

Comment: Agreed, Indexes has been already placed, even we wrote queries based on paulwhite from sqlperformce.com. we are doing lot of updates and inserts in #temp tables used inside the stored procedure. that why i am asking for the replace of #temp with MOTS

Comment: In theory, memory optimised tables, _along with_ the natively compiled stored procedures that go with them should see a performance increase. But without the accompanying natively compiled stored procedures you probably won't see any difference. So your first step is to understand all the limitations in natively compiled stored procedures and see if you can even convert what you have. Just one other thing: You should never see any activity in your paging file. If your paging file is in use, you need to add more RAM.

Comment: @Kannan.C why are you using temp tables in the first place? What calculations are you performing?

Comment: `100 #temp tables to hold the intermediate results` that's a problem by itself. Unless you've placed tempdb on its own RAID cluster with fast disks with roughly 1 filegroup per core, you are probably using the slowest storage in your system to perform ETL. Which, btw shouldn't be done like this. Use SSIS to process data as a stream in a pipeline of transformations, storing intermediate results *only if needed* in *actual* tables stored in separate filegroups. This way you can inspect and optimize the schema of the tables, add or remove indexes where required.

Comment: BTW I have quite a few multimillion row tables too. I don't run queries against them though, I pull changed data and update columnstore fact tables.  I don't use temp tables. I use columnstores a lot, gaining both compression and in-memory benefits.

Comment: Yes, you can use memory-optimized tables even if your database is 2 TB. The idea is that the memory-optimized tables must fit in memory, not necessarily your whole database. As to whether it will really bring the benefits you're looking for, only testing can tell. One important problem you may face is that temp tables have default scoping and nesting properties that regular tables don't have. [Memory-optimized table variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization) are a closer match.

Comment: I always have doubts when someone claims in the start that the database is already optimized. Usually that means that it's really not, but just one or two things were made to speed up the previous version. You should really explain here what exactly you think this will improve -- are you temp. tables too big to fit in memory (meaning are the estimates wrong), also writing in tempdb should be with kinda delayed durability, so that shouldn't slow you down that much anyhow.